# VS Code - Blue underline and strange colors

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I've been using Intellij for Java, and today tried to use VS Code. However, when I open my file there are several [visual issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21Z2.png)

throws have "t" and "s" have a lighter colour

IOException has "tion" greyed out and has a blue wavy underline.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: @CfloweVisit click the link

Comment: I don't really know what's going on... can you close VSCode and open again?

Comment: What is your linter ? You can find it in VS Code settings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you show what is the wavy line prompt?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H21Z2.png

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem before, generally when it lags a little. A trick I use is delete part of it (where it is complaining, sometime just the bracket) and then undo, so that it re-parses it, and sees that it is valid.

Comment: So _that's_ what they mean by "Code Editing Redefined".